# AWS EC2 - reverse DNS and port 25 blocked by AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smtp, mail-server, reverse-dns

I am trying to set up my own Email server on EC2 instance, but facing issue related reverse DNS and SMTP port 25:

> Incoming Mail (SMTP/postfix) is running but is not publicly accessible at X.X.X.X:25.
>
> Outbound mail (SMTP port 25) seems to be blocked by your network. You will not be able to send any mail. Many residential networks block port 25 to prevent hijacked machines from being able to send spam. A quick connection test to Google's mail server on port 25 failed.
>
> Your box's reverse DNS is currently ec2-x-x-x-x.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com, but it should be mail.xyz.com. Your ISP or cloud provider will have instructions on setting up reverse DNS for your box.

By googling I found [Request to remove email sending limitations](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/contacts?#/rdns-limits) link, I requested by this form to AWS, but didn't getting any solution.

Please guide me on this.

Comment: [Remove the Port 25 Restriction From Your EC2 Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/)

Comment: I am using other DNS service, not Route 53. I have already submitted "Request to Remove Email Sending Limitations" form. But I do not get solution.